# Problems with React Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following problem, i have a table with some data, and this table have an "edit" button. Now, i have an "Editar" component for this.

This is my App.js.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render(){
  return (

<Container style = {{padding:"0",margin:"0"}} fluid>
    
<Row>
  <Col>
      <Router>
          <Switch>
                <Route path = "/dashboard">
                   <Index/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/solicitud">
                    <Solicitud/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/reserva">
                   <Reserva />
                </Route>
                <Redirect from =  "/" to="/dashboard" />
          </Switch>
     </Router>

    </Col>
    
  </Row>
 </Container>  

  )
  }}
export default App;
```

Inside this  "Index"  component (in /dashboard path), i have the following table.

[image]

This is my "Index" component render function

```
 
    render(){
    
      return(
        <Container  style = {{padding:"0",margin:"0"}} fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col style = {{textAlign: "right"}}  >
            <Button  href = "/solicitud" variant="primary">Agregar una Solicitud</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
          <Col md = {10}>
              <h3 style = {{marginLeft:"40px"}}>Solicitudes</h3>
              <List ItemList = {listsol} res = "0" />
              </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
          <Col md = {10}>
            <h3 style = {{marginLeft:"40px"}}>Reservas</h3>
              <List ItemList = {listres} res = "1"/>
            </Col>
         </Row>
     </Container>
   
      )}};
```

Now inside "Index" i create the tables with "List" component, where i create the "Editar" Button

List.js render function.

```
render(){
    var res = this.props.res;


    const lista = this.props.ItemList;
    if (parseInt(res) === 0){
    var todoItems = lista.map((obj) =>

  <tr key={obj.id}>
    <td>{obj.fecha}</td>
    <td> {obj.hora}</td>
   <td> {obj.equipo? "Sí":"No"}</td>
    <td>{obj.equipamiento? "Sí":"No"}</td>
    <td> {obj.sillon?"Sí":"No"}</td>  
    <td> {obj.paciente.rut} </td>
    <td><Button  variant="primary">Aprobar</Button> {''}
/*here i create the path */
    <Router>
        <Route path = "/dashboard/editar">
              <Editar id = {obj.id} fecha = {obj.fecha} hora = {obj.hora} equipamiento = {obj.equipamiento} 
              sillon = {obj.sillon} rut = {obj.paciente.rut} />
         </Route>
   </Router>
/* here i create Editar Button */
    <Button href = "/dashboard/editar" variant="primary">Editar</Button>{' '}
    <Button onClick = {()=>{this.handleDel(obj.id)}} variant="danger">Rechazar Solicitud</Button></td>
  </tr>);
    }
    else if (parseInt(res) === 1){
        var todoItems = lista.map((obj) =>

  <tr key={obj.id}>
    <td>{obj.fecha}</td>
    <td> {obj.hora}</td>
   <td> {obj.equipo? "Sí":"No"}</td>
    <td>{obj.equipamiento? "Sí":"No"}</td>
    <td> {obj.sillon?"Sí":"No"}</td>    
    <td> {obj.paciente.rut} </td>
    <td><Button  onClick = {()=>{this.handleDel(obj.id)}}  variant="primary">Terminar Procedimiento</Button> {''}
    <Button  variant="danger">Cancelar Reserva</Button></td>
  </tr>);
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Equipo</th>
      <th>Equipamiento</th>
      <th>Sillón</th>
      <th>Rut</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {todoItems}
</tbody>
</Table>
</Container>
      );
    


}
}
```

With this, when i press "Editar" Button this component renders inside the table, i suppose that its because i'm creating the path inside other component.

[image]

I tried creating the path in my App.js but i dont know how can i give the params to the component.
Sorry for so long question.

Comment: you could simply add params like this /dashboard/editar/:id. so whatever you pass in as id will something like this  /dashboard/editar/3434534

Comment: you mean, create that path on App.js?

Comment: You're putting a `<Router />` inside your table, and this is what you'll get. Like Jonathan says, simply `<Link to={...}>` and put the `<Route>` in your App.js `<Switch>`.